# functions of n variables and their partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an unknown function, and suppose that you are given $n$ other functions $f^{i}:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfy:
$\forall i, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $f^i(x) = \partial^i f(x)$.
For any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ find a formula for $f(y) - f(x)$ which involves only the $f^i$'s.
I'm a kinda new in this subject of multivariable calculus, so I don't really have an intuition to it and I'm sitting in this question for a couple of hours and can't see how I can find this formula.
Would be glad for some help.

Comment: [Multivariate Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_for_multivariate_functions) around $\textbf{x}$?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see the connection

Comment: In "formula for $f(y) - f(x)$ which involves only the $f^i$'s", what kind of formula? Some context would help.